# write: Connection reset by peer

Tags: openssh

When I open my PC (Ubuntu 19.04) and try to log in for the first time in my `ssh` server (Raspbian buster) I get `write: connection reset by peer`:

```
trp@trp-pc:~$ ssh -vvv pi@192.168.2.251
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.2.251 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.251 [192.168.2.251] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/trp/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
write: Connection reset by peer
```

But if I `ping` the server or try to `ssh` two times I get connected and everything works perfectly (no disconnects etc.) and I can have multiple ssh sessions with the server. If I reboot my PC the problem appears again (for the first login attempt).

**Update #1 :**
I checked the logs (auth.log) but even with `LogLevel DEBUG3` the failed login attempt doesn't exist.

**Update #2 :**
I tried to specify Mac , Kex and Key but nothing changed (`ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group16-sha512 -o MACS=umac-128-etm@openssh.com -o HostbasedKeyTypes=ssh-rsa -c aes192-ctr`)

Comment: Also check the logs on the server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my router/modem. I changed the address pool back to default ( from .2 to .254 ) , I deleted the static ip for my server ( that I had set up in my router/modem settings ) , connected to my server and set a static ip. Now everything runs smoothly.